# Turning BSPMapGen demo into a flxTilemap object

Tags: haxeflixel

I'm trying to use the BSPMapGen demo to generate maps for my game but I'm having issues. The resulting map contains too many rooms and the hallways are twice as thick as they need to be. My guess was that the code uses the game dimensions somewhere but I couldn't find it.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrJSJ.png)

Here is the code (only has several changes from GenerateState):

```
package mapgen;

import flixel.tile.FlxTilemap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flixel.util.FlxStringUtil;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.util.FlxColor;

class BSPMap extends FlxTilemap 
{

    var TILE_SIZE:Int = 16;

    public static var mapData:BitmapData;

    var rooms:Array<Rectangle>;
    var hallways:Array<Rectangle>;
    var leafs:Array<Leaf>;
    var mapWidth:Int;
    var mapHeight:Int;

    public function new(w:Int, h:Int, tilesize:Int) 
    {
        super();
        TILE_SIZE = tilesize;
        mapWidth = w;
        mapHeight = h;
        generateMap();
        var csvData:String = FlxStringUtil.bitmapToCSV(mapData);
        this.loadMapFromCSV(csvData, "assets/tiles.png", TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, AUTO);

    }

        function generateMap():Void
    {
        // Reset mapData
        mapData = new BitmapData(mapWidth, mapHeight, false, FlxColor.BLACK);

        // Reset arrays
        rooms = [];
        hallways = [];
        leafs = [];

        // First, create leaf to be root of all leaves
        var root = new Leaf(0, 0, mapWidth, mapHeight);
        leafs.push(root);

        var didSplit:Bool = true;
        // Loop through every Leaf in array until no more can be split
        while (didSplit)
        {
            didSplit = false;

            for (leaf in leafs)
            {
                if (leaf.leftChild == null && leaf.rightChild == null) // If not split
                {
                    // If this leaf is too big, or 75% chance
                    if (leaf.width > Leaf.MAX_SIZE || leaf.height > Leaf.MAX_SIZE || FlxG.random.float() > 0.25)
                    {
                        if (leaf.split()) // split the leaf!
                        {
                            // If split worked, push child leafs into vector
                            leafs.push(leaf.leftChild);
                            leafs.push(leaf.rightChild);
                            didSplit = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Next, iterate through each leaf and create room in each one
        root.createRooms();

        for (leaf in leafs)
        {
            // Then draw room and hallway (if there is one)
            if (leaf.room != null)
            {
                drawRoom(leaf.room);
            }

            if (leaf.hallways != null && leaf.hallways.length > 0)
            {
                drawHalls(leaf.hallways);
            }
        }

        //updateSprite();
    }

    function drawHalls(hallRect:Array<Rectangle>):Void
    {
        for (rect in hallRect)
        {
            hallways.push(rect);
            mapData.fillRect(rect, FlxColor.WHITE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add this room to room array, then draw onto mapData
     */
    function drawRoom(roomRect:Rectangle):Void
    {
        rooms.push(roomRect);
        mapData.fillRect(roomRect, FlxColor.WHITE);
    }

}
```